# Why is Groovy copying objects without prompting and reassigning fields?

Tags: json, grails, groovy, jvm, object-identity

This is so bizarre I have no idea how to even properly formulate this question, but hopefully some guru recognises what is going on here and can help me.

I am working on a Grails project that is exhibiting a bizarre bug. While marshalling a controller's response to JSON, it throws this exception:

```
Caused by: org.grails.web.json.JSONException: Misplaced key: expected mode of KEY but was OBJECT
    at org.grails.web.json.JSONWriter.key(JSONWriter.java:237)
    at org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.DomainClassMarshaller.marshalObject(DomainClassMarshaller.java:169)
    at org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.DomainClassMarshaller.marshalObject(DomainClassMarshaller.java:59)
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```

The complete object tree it is marshalling is an `ArrayList` of `Form` objects, and at this point it is marshalling a `Form` object, specifically it's adding its primary key as a property to the JSON object.

Here is the relevant code from `DomainClassMarshaller`:

```java
    public void marshalObject(Object value, JSON json) throws ConverterException {
        JSONWriter writer = json.getWriter();

        // (...)

        writer.object();

        // (...)

        PersistentProperty id = domainClass.getIdentity();
        if(id != null) {
            if(shouldInclude(includeExcludeSupport, includes, excludes, value, id.getName())) {
                Object idValue = extractValue(value, id);
                if(idValue != null) {
                    json.property(id.getName(), idValue); // <-- JSONException thrown here
                }
            }    
        }

        // (...)
    }
```

And here are `JSONObject.getWriter()`:

```java
    public JSONWriter getWriter() throws ConverterException {
        return writer;
    }
```

...and `JSONObject.property()`:

```java
    public void property(String key, Object value) throws JSONException, ConverterException {
        writer.key(key); // <-- Throws JSONException if writer.mode is not KEY
        value(value);
    }
```

So the exception happens when the `json.property(id.getName(), idValue)` is invoked, because at that point `json.writer` is in mode `OBJECT`, while it expects to be in mode `KEY`.

**But here is the bizarre part: even though `writer == json.writer`, `writer` is in mode `KEY` while `json.writer` is in mode `OBJECT`!!!** It has been copied somehow, at some point, while its mode was still `OBJECT`, so that now it is in the wrong state and an exception is thrown.

I have verified this with a debugger. Even though the code does `writer = json.getWriter()`, and `JSON.getWriter()` just does `return writer`, after that lines returns, *`writer` is a different instance than `json.writer`!* I can tell this from the object IDs. And in fact, the identity of `json.writer` *keeps* changing after that!

I have no idea how this is possible. I can see it happen in a debugger. I have set a "when modified" breakpoint on the `JSONObject.writer` field to see who or what is changing it, but that is never hit. I have set a breakpoint in the constructor of `JSONWriter` to see who or what is making all these copies, but that too is never hit beyond the first time.

Here is the code again, with some annotations added to illustrate what I see in a debugger when I step through it. I'm pretty confident that the same thing happens when *not* running in a debugger, because exactly the same exception is thrown:

```java
    public void marshalObject(Object value, JSON json) throws ConverterException {
        // json.writer == JSONWriter@123
        JSONWriter writer = json.getWriter();
        // writer == JSONWriter@134
        // json.writer == JSONWriter@145

        // (...)

        writer.object();
        // writer == JSONWriter@134
        // writer.mode == KEY
        // json.writer == JSONWriter@156
        // json.writer.mode == OBJECT

        // (...)

        PersistentProperty id = domainClass.getIdentity();
        if(id != null) {
            if(shouldInclude(includeExcludeSupport, includes, excludes, value, id.getName())) {
                Object idValue = extractValue(value, id);
                if(idValue != null) {
                    // This should work, since writer should == json.writer, and writer.mode == KEY,
                    // but instead json.writer is now a different instance of JSONWriter,
                    // and json.writer.mode is still OBJECT:
                    json.property(id.getName(), idValue); // <-- JSONException thrown here
                }
            }    
        }
        // (...)
    }
```

Please help me figure out what on Earth is going on here!

Some versions:
Grails: 5.2.4
Groovy: 3.0.11
Java: Eclipse Adoptium Temurin-11.0.18+10

Comment: Would it be possible to share a simple controller method that reproduces the bug/issue?

Comment: What you have in key? And how corresponding class/property declared. Also in your last trace you are evaluating `json.writer` a lot that is equivalent of `json.getWriter()` that I bet creates a new json writer object - that could explain new object id each time.

Comment: @wubbalubba, unfortunately not, this is in a proprietary codebase and it doesn't seem to happen with a simple test case (I'm sure it would have long been caught and fixed if it did).

Comment: @daggett, no, getWriter() is a simple JavaBeans getter that returns a field. `key` at this point is set to "id".